Radzen Theme not applying in Blazor Web App
So, my App.razor  looks like this:
    @using Radzen.Blazor
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
<head>
    <RadzenTheme Theme="material" @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveWebAssembly" />



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/material3-base.css">



</head>


<script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js?v=@(typeof(Radzen.Colors).Assembly.GetName().Version)"></script>

It simply doesn't apply, but when I apply dark.cs it works, why? is it a bug with radzen?

I think you confused about the rendermode. According to your codes, you are using "blazor WASM standalone" template. Following codes needs to be added to wwwroot/index.html https://blazor.radzen.com/get-started/wasm
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/material-base.css">
</head>
<body>
...
<script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js"></script>
</body>

Only when you are using "blazor web app" template, follwoing codes should be added to app.razor https://blazor.radzen.com/get-started/net8
<head>
...
<RadzenTheme Theme="humanistic" @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
</head>
<body>
...
<script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js?v=@(typeof(Radzen.Colors).Assembly.GetName().Version)"></script>
</body>

To clarify where should add stylesheet and script. 
blazor web app (.net8) : App.razor
blazor server app (.net7) : _host.cshtml 
balzor webAssembly standalone : index.html 
